# Multiple if conditions on pandas dataframe with different thresholds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several parameters:

```
par1      par2      par3      par4      par5       
1.122208  1.054132  1.133250  1.114845  1.183850
1.076445  1.128663  0.998518  1.081816  1.006934
1.077058  1.561871  1.045255  1.120456  1.768667
0.904869  1.183985  0.938095  0.927841  1.201934
0.876596  1.044014  0.877457  0.871429  0.990452
...
```

The value of each parameter needs to be checked against a specific threshold.  I need to check whether *at least* two of the above parameters are above the aforementioned thresholds. It does not matter which parameters are above the threshold, as long as there are at least two of them. Note that par1 has a threshold1, par2 a threshold2 and so on, with threshold1 different from threshold2,..., threshold5 and so on.

So far I have written an ugly nested if condition, but I was wondering what would be the best approach here.

Comment: each and every value in the above datafame is a parameter? Is that a dataframe without column names? Where can we find the thresholds?  Do you have a threshold for each value or for each column? What happens to the parameter if it's above the threshold, and what happens if it's below the threshold? What would be your ideal result?

Comment: Yes sorry, each column is a parameter, so par1, ..., par5. Then if two of the parameters are above the threshold(s) I select the corresponding row. For the actual values of the thresholds, let's just say threshold1 = 1.5, threshold2 = 3, threshold3 = 1.2, threhsold4 =1.5, threshold5=3.

Comment: Sorry i don't mean to be rude. I just think your question needs much more information.

Comment: No problem! Do you need more info? Because all I am asking is how to select a row when at least two conditions are met. If I had two columns only I would do ```df = df[(df.par1 > threshold1) & (df.par2 > threshold2)]. However, I am now facing the problem of having to select at least two out of the five columns, no matter the order, so that I have ten possible combinations. I don't know whether this is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help solve your problem?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    'par1': [1.122208, 1.076445, 1.077058, 0.904869, 0.876596],
    'par2': [1.054132, 1.128663, 1.561871, 1.183985, 1.044014],
    'par3': [1.133250, 0.998518, 1.045255, 0.938095, 0.877457],
    'par4': [1.114845, 1.081816, 1.120456, 0.927841, 0.871429],
    'par5': [1.183850, 1.006934, 1.768667, 1.201934, 0.990452],
  }
)

thresholds = {
  'par1': 0.5,
  'par2': 3,
  'par3': 1.2,
  'par4': 1.1,
  'par5': 3,
}

def check_thresholds(input_row):
  no_over_threshold = sum(
    [value > thresholds[col_name] for col_name, value in input_row.items()]
  )

  if no_over_threshold >= 2:
    return True
  else:
    return False

df['above_thresholds'] = df.apply(check_thresholds, axis=1)
```

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using Kelvin Ducray's sample data, we can take the solution a step further, to avoid the for-loop/apply, and use Pandas' vectorized operations, which should be faster:

```py
thresholds = pd.Series(thresholds)

# compare df with thresholds
# sum accross the booleans
# check True or False for >=2
above_thresholds = df.gt(thresholds).sum(1).ge(2)

df.assign(above_thresholds = above_thresholds)

       par1      par2      par3      par4      par5  above_thresholds
0  1.122208  1.054132  1.133250  1.114845  1.183850              True
1  1.076445  1.128663  0.998518  1.081816  1.006934             False
2  1.077058  1.561871  1.045255  1.120456  1.768667              True
3  0.904869  1.183985  0.938095  0.927841  1.201934             False
4  0.876596  1.044014  0.877457  0.871429  0.990452             False
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer

Comment: Incredible solution!